# Is the weak field assumption compatible with black hole considerations?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

The Schwarzschild solution is based on the assumption of a weak gravitational field, so all speculations about event horizons and black holes (i.e. in the area of a strong gravitational field), are just intellectual exercises with no mathematical justification! Is this not the case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks _very_ clear what the OP is asking - an invalid question based on an incorrect assumption!  I do not think "clarification" will help here, unless it is to to explain how they came to that incorrect assumption.  I think the OP should just delete it to avoid (justified) downvotes.

Answer (score 6):

> The Schwarzschild solution is based on the assumption of a weak gravitational field,...

No its not. The Schwarzschild solution is an exact solution to the full nonlinear vacuum Einstein equation. No weak field approximation anywhere in sight.

Comment: @Margherita If you are try to say that the Einstein-Hilbert action is "just" the low energy effective of some more fundamental theory then many people will agree. But in that sense, the occurrence of horizons is not a "strong field" phenomenon, and can occur arbitrarily far in the "weak field" by looking at a sufficiently large black hole.

Comment: This is what I had in mind. The Schwarzschild solution itself is of course without any approximations.

Comment: Independently on the black hole size, the locally measured acceleration*, in its proximity, is always tending to infinity; that, measured by an external observer - to zero. At the event horizon, there are always very strong field conditions.
(*by acceleration I mean this from a standstill)